# How can i execute http request from not-main thread in unity?

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, web, unity-game-engine

I use [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html) library for Unity in C#. When i call function Send from main thread it's ok.

```
PostWorker pw = new PostWorker();    
API.instance.StartCoroutine(pw.Send(url, postParams));
```

But when i try make it from PostWorker

```
API.instance.StartCoroutine(Send(url, postParams));
```

it's not work with such error:

> StartCoroutine_Auto can only be called from the main thread.

If I call the function without `Coroutine` it doesn't work and not enter in `Send`.

```
private IEnumerator Send(string path, Dictionary<string, string> postData)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    if (postData != null && postData.Any())
    {
        foreach (var item in postData)
        {
            form.AddField(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }

    WWW www = new WWW(path, form);
    yield return www;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log(www.text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
}
```

So, how can i execute http request from not-main thread?

Comment: Why would you need a separate thread? Generally you don't want to call any UnityEngine code from a different thread.

Comment: I need to use second thread for post messages queue.